# SonarCloud: Got 500 error - Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.MetadataPublisher when execute mvn verify sonar:sonar

Tags: sonarcloud

When I execute `mvn clean verify sonar:sonar`, I get 500 error from maven about:

> `Failed to execute goal
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar`
>   because: `Unable to load component class
>   org.sonar.scanner.report.MetadataPublisher: Unable to load component
>   class org.sonar.scanner.rule.ModuleQProfiles: Error 500 on
>   https://sonarcloud.io/api/qualityprofiles/search.protobuf?projectKey=LazyDevelopment%3ALister&organization=lazydevelopment-bitbucket
>   : {"errors":[{"msg":"An error has occurred. Please contact your
>   administrator"}]} -> [Help 1]`

Project is https://bitbucket.org/LazyDevelopment/lister

Current branch is https://bitbucket.org/LazyDevelopment/lister/branch/7-fix-issues

It worked fine before yesterday's evening. Today I tried to

- hardcode maven plugin version in mvn command
- re-issued tocken for SonarCloud account (new and valid tocken commited only to this branch),

But without success.

I executed the same command with -X switch, but didn't find any useful info there. Tried to find a way to attach the file with output here, but didn't. Anyway, project is opened on BitBucket, so you could go to Pipelines and check last failed jobs or download sources and reproduce the issue.

Comment: We are looking at the problem currently, I will keep you posted.

Comment: I've just noticed on the quality profiles of your organization that the T-SQL "Sonar way" is not set as default: can you set it as default? (you can do it in the "actions" menu on the right side of the list)

Comment: I currently have the same issue, didn't change my configuration since the last run. Already tried it with another token but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to fix the issue is the following:

1. Go to your organization "Quality Profiles" page
2. Scroll down to the T-SQL language
3. You will notice that the "Sonar way" quality profile for this language is not set as default
4. On the right side of the line, click on the gear icon and click on "Set as Default"

Once this is done, your analyses should be running fine again.